# CFRange cannot cross-byte when using CFBitVectorGetBits

Tags: objective-c, bit, cfbitvector

```
Byte a[2]={85, 15};
Byte b[2]={0};
CFBitVectorRef bv1 = CFBitVectorCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, a, 16);
CFRange r1 = {3, 8};
CFBitVectorGetBits(bv1, r1, b);
```

Byte a[2] are "0101 0101 0000 1111", I want to cut the {3,8} (1010 1000) of CFRange into another Byte b[2].  But I got nothing in b[2].  But if I change the range to {0,8} or {8,8}, it works.  Why cannot get the bits cross-byte?

Comment: This looks like a bug in CoreFoundation. `{3, 5}` works, but `{3, 6}` does not.

Comment: yup, since {3,5} is still not cross byte, still in the first byte. but {3, 6} does.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that the problem is that the problem is really that the range crosses a byte boundary, not the alignment of the range. Btw: the source code is at http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/CFBitVector.c, so your can try to find the error (-: I would recommend to file a bug at bugreporter.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i have exactly the same problem. CFBitVectorGetBits sets my *bytes to nil, when i am using {7,7} range. Found any solution?
I'm implementing it by stupidly iterating over bits for now.
EDIT:
Adding code:

```
CFBitVectorRef source = ... ;// Some source bit vector
CFIndex location = 7;//Current location in bit vector
uint8 *bytes = malloc(sizeof(uint8));
//CFBitVectorGetBits(source, CFRangeMake(location,7), bytes);//This one is bugged
CFBitVectorRef buffer = CFBitVectorCreateMutable(NULL,7);
CFBitVectorSetCount(buffer, 7);
for (CFIndex i=0; i<7; i++)
CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(buffer, i, CFBitVectorGetBitAtIndex(source, location+i));
CFBitVectorGetBits(buffer, CFRangeMake(0, 7), bytes);
//Now *bytes contains needed bits
```

Works as needed.